# Kotlin - onclicklistener for recyclerview to a "details" fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show another fragment upon clicking a recyclerview item. I already added an onclicklistener, now there's a todo part on the fragment.kt, which I need to know how to have it navigate to a new fragment

As for the code, here's the adapter:

```
class dormAdapter(
    private val dorms: List<Dorms>,
    private val listener: RecyclerViewClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<dormAdapter.DormViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = dorms.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        DormViewHolder(
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.layout_home,
                parent, false
            )
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DormViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.recyclerviewDormBinding.dorm = dorms[position]
        holder.recyclerviewDormBinding.buttonReserve.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onRecyclerViewItemClick(holder.recyclerviewDormBinding.buttonReserve, dorms[position])
        }
        holder.recyclerviewDormBinding.layoutBox.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onRecyclerViewItemClick(holder.recyclerviewDormBinding.layoutBox, dorms[position])
        }
    }

    inner class DormViewHolder(
        val recyclerviewDormBinding: LayoutHomeBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(recyclerviewDormBinding.root)

}
```

Here's the Fragment on the landing page:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), RecyclerViewClickListener {

    private lateinit var factory: HomeViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val api = DormsAPI()
        val repository = DormRepository(api)

        factory = HomeViewModelFactory(repository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.getDorms()

        viewModel.dorms.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { dorms ->
            recyclerViewDorms.also{
                it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                it.setHasFixedSize(true)
                it.adapter = dormAdapter(dorms, this)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onRecyclerViewItemClick(view: View, dorms: Dorms) {
        when(view.id){
            R.id.button_reserve -> {
                **// TODO: Go to new account if not signed up, etc...**
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Reserve button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            R.id.layoutBox -> {
                **// TODO: Go to Dorm Details**
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Go to dorm details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anything else needed for this question will be followed up for later.

**HUGE EDIT**: Onclicklistener is now added. Project is now good for MVVM architecture.

Comment: Have you gone through 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

You should go thought some tutorial and do some research. I am pretty sure you will find lots of link/blog to do what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare mOnclicklistener property in Adapter class

```
private val mOnClickListener: View.OnClickListener

init {
     mOnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
         Log.d("onclick of item")
     }
 }
```

2) In onBindViewHolder function setOnclick listener

```
with(holder.mView) {
        setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener)
    }
```